# ZK upload dialog not working

Tags: java, zk

I am using Fileupload.get() to upload file and that is working fine.

However, I want to change how the upload dialog look (like add more button and change position of the text) so I modified the `fileuploaddlg.zul` in my `zkStyle/web/zul/html` folder and in my java code I added `Fileupload.setTemplate("~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg.zul")` before `Fileupload.get()`.

This didn't modify upload dialog at all so I added `fileuploaddlg2.zul` to `zkStyle/web/zul/html` folder and changed `setTemplate` to `Fileupload.setTemplate("~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg2.zul")`. This time I got an error saying `~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg2.zul doesnt't exist.`

What am I doing wrong? how can I modify how the upload dialog look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an URI starting with `~./`, ZK assumes the resource is from the class path. 
So you should move your template file to the class path. 
Another option (and I think the one you are looking for) is to use URI that is relative to the webapp context root, and in that case don't use `~./` prefix.

Comment: if I use ~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg.zul for the URI, then the program runs fine, but if I use something different like ~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg2.zul then the program will give me an error saying that file doesnt exist, so does doesnt that mean the path im using is correct?

Comment: @help `~./zul/html/fileuploaddlg.zul` is a URI for the default fileupload dialog template in ZK (see https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/org/zkoss/zul/Fileupload.java) and this zul is already included in the `zul.jar` (https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/archive/web/zul/html/fileuploaddlg.zul). So the path is absolutely correct but points to the wrong file (not yours, I mean).