# Relative URL to images in css (Zkoss)

Tags: java, css, components, zk

I developed a component in ZK 7.0.0 with own molds, styles etc. The component should be build in one jar file, which I can copy in WEB-INF/lib folder to replace standart ZK components.

Folder structure:

- src/
- src/main/resources/web/images/
- src/main/resources/web/js/

In ".css.dsp" files I use statements likes:

> background-image:url(${c:encodeURL('/images/in2.png')}

And it's refer to 'domen/webapp/images/in2.png'. (physical path: /webapp/images/in2.png). But I need get images from jar file.

So how can I write relative path to images in css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are faced with the case that is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669095/zk-upload-dialog-not-working).

To reference a URI that points to a file on the classpath you should use a special prefix `~./`:

```
background-image:url(${c:encodeURL('~./images/in2.png')}
```

Some more details could be found in the docs for methods [WebApp.getResource](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/WebApp.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [Execution.locate](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Execution.html#locate%28java.lang.String%29).
Real world examples can be seen in ZK [source files](https://github.com/zkoss/zkthemes/blob/6.5-Stable/silvertail/src/archive/web/silvertail/js/zul/inp/css/input.css.dsp#L124).

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thank you. http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Customization_Guide/Integrate_with_LESS/How_ZK_works_with_LESS/ZK_LESS_Functions#Core_Functions